# cannot load new scene

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm loading the default scene perfect "MainScene". but when y load a scene created by mi
the application crash

THIS WOKS OK

```
  - (CCScene*) startScene
  {
       return [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"];
  }
```

THIS MAKES THE APP CRASH

```
  - (CCScene*) startScene
  {
       return [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"miNewScene"];
  }

   miNewScene : CCScene
```

EXCEPTION @"Argument must be non-nil"

does anyone knows what might be happening here?
Thanks in advance
Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have a CCB document in SpriteBuilder named `miNewScene.ccb`.

It does not suffice to just have a CCScene subclass by that name. CCBReader loads a CCB document, and if necessary it will instantiate the custom class associated with the document. It does not instantiate classes.

If you want to launch with a non-SpriteBuilder scene, do this:

```
- (CCScene*) startScene
{
    return [miNewScene node];
}
```

Note that it is customary in Objective-C to start class names with uppercase letters so as to not confuse them with variables/properties which are supposed to begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, I thought that only creating the new scene through Xcode and calling this funcion That would be enough 
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

If you use SpriteBuilder, the Best way to load a custom CCScene:

```
MainScene *mainScene = (MainScene *)[CCBReader load:@"MainScene"];
/** Reset contentSize : SpriteBuilder changes this **/
mainScene.contentSizeType = CCSizeTypePoints;
mainScene.contentSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].designSize;
```

No children of another container and less memory footprint